# How to change grid column header name on combo box select at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, combobox

How to change grid column header name on combo box select at run time

Hi Everyone, I want to change the column name of a grid on selecting a
 value from the combo box.

Please share some information

I am trying but it's not working

```
grid.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(columnIndex).setText("New Title");
```

Comment: Assuming that you have the grid inside the UpdatePanel

Comment: yes...............